# python Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, c

My python version is **python-2.7.3**. My program has ran about **3 hours** for doing **the same thing**. However, I got an error"**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**". I viewed the dmesg log,got

```
[466109.911462] python[8090]: segfault at 9c859249 ip 00000000004c79b8 sp 00007f3c8affa810 error 4 in python2.7[400000+21f000]
[479310.742822] python[8127]: segfault at 7fadbbfffff8 ip 00007fadd233a9a3 sp 00007fadae7f9da8 error 4 in libc-2.15.so[7fadd21f8000+1b5000]
```

**Question:** How can I debug the error?

Comment: is that all you get? if you can post your program code - may help.

Comment: Sorry, but I can not post the code, for it is a bit long.What I want to get is the debug method

Comment: Use `nm` to list the symbols for both `python2.7` and `libc-2.15.so` - try to find the symbol where the instruction pointers `00000000004c79b8` and `00007fadd233a9a3` point to (these addresses will probably be slightly less in nm. Other that than it is hard to know.

Comment: ah but cannot get symbols from libc-2.17.so... if you are lucky and have the debug symbols intact

Comment: Sane question, sometimes this is all info you can have, and must debug based on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `objdump -d` to disassemble the binary files, and search for the locations `00000000004c79b8` and `00007fadd233a9a3` could give you some idea, or then not.

Thus on my computer for example

```
objdump -d /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so|less
```

The starting address for libc-2.17 is `7fadd21f8000`, so I think you must subtract this from the pointer value

```
>>> hex(0x00007fadd233a9a3-0x7fadd21f8000)
'0x1429a3'
```

So that is what you'd be looking for in libc (I think),

As for python, no adjustment is needed as the executable would be linked to its preferred address.